# How to determine what is the appropriate lameduck parameter value in coredns?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, coredns

The below snippet is taken from default Corefile of coredns.

```
data:  
  Corefile: |    
  .:53 {
        errors
        health {
            lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
```

I am aware that lameduck will delay shutdown for DURATION specified. I could not get the exact usage of this lameduck. I believe when we do rolling restart, coredns pod will get shutdown and get replaced. So why we are delaying shutdown using lameduck? And I see 5s is the default value comes in coredns deployment, based on which parameter we can choose lameduck duration? It would be really helpful if someone provides your suggestion and an example use-case scenario of having lameduck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Adding lameduck to the health plugin minimizes DNS resolution failures during a [CoreDNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns-configmap-options) pod restart or deployment rollout. This does come at the expense of increased rollout times. A lameduck anywhere from 5 to 10 seconds eliminates most DNS resolution failures. The lameduck duration is entirely dependent on the readiness polling interval, picking a single default duration is problematic.

When entering lame duck mode, the server will send a message to clients. Some maintainer supported clients will invoke an optional callback indicating that a server is entering lame duck mode. This is used for cases where an application can benefit from preparing for the short outage between the time it is evicted and automatically reconnected to another server.

In production we recommend that a server is shut down with ​lame duck mode​ as a graceful way to slowly evict clients. With large deployments this mitigates the "thundering herd" situation that will place CPU pressure on servers as TLS enabled clients reconnect. After entering lame duck mode, the server will stop accepting new connections, wait for a 10 second grace period, then begin to evict clients over a period of time configurable by the lame_duck_duration configuration option.

Refer [Add lameduck to recommend Kubernetes deployment configuration](https://github.com/coredns/deployment/issues/199) for more information.